# How to set CMake parameter -j on Ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

When building with CMAKE in two different codebases the option -j 16 is used, which tends to cause problems where -j 4 doesn't.  Is there a global option for this?  I can't find where to change it in Visual Studio Code CmakeTools.

Answer (score 0):

Read this quickly before and admin deletes it :).

`-j[cpu_count]` is an argument to the generator (eg make) and as such can't be set by CMake in itself.
My advice is to either use eg Ninja (which handles this for you) or invoke CMake via a wrapper script that sets this depending on the codebase in question.
Eg in python3 `f'-j{cpu_count()}'`.